# Add data from FCM notification to a Flutter List?

Tags: json, flutter, listview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add the data from a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification to a list.

```
final List<FCMContent> fcmcrafts = [];
```

The list is created from JSON data that has been downloaded from an external PHP page.

```
if (response.body.contains('audioid')) {
    List fcmcrafts = json.decode(response.body);
    return fcmcrafts.map((fcmcraft) => FCMContent.fromJson(fcmcraft)).toList();
}
```

Here's the class I've got for FCMContent;

```
class FCMContent {

  final String audioid, name, title;

  FCMContent({
    this.audioid,
    this.name,
    this.title,
  });

  factory FCMContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) =>FCMContent(
      audioid: jsonData['audioid'],
      name: jsonData['name'],
      title: jsonData['title']
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "audioid":audioid,
    "name":name,
    "title":title
  };
}
```

How do I add the FCM notification to the list? Here's how I would add it if it were a string.

```
 @override
 void onNotify(RemoteMessage notification) {
  _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(notification);
 setState(() {
  _notification = notification;
  fcmcrafts.insert(0, _notification?.notification?.title ?? "");
  });
}
```

But how do I add the FCM notification which arrives as JSON code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do something like this

fcmcrafts.insert(0, FCMContent.fromJson(_notification),);

you simply need to convert RemoteMessage to FCMContent maybe you can create a custom constructor FCMContent.fromRemoteMessage() and map the fields.

Comment: How do I convert RemoteMessage to FCMContent ? I've got a class called FCMContent which I use to map the JSON coming from the http query ; class FCMContent {

  final String audioid, name, title;

  FCMContent({
    this.audioid,
    this.name,
    this.title,
  });

  factory FCMContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) =>FCMContent(
      audioid: jsonData['audioid'],
      name: jsonData['name'],
      title: jsonData['title']
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "audioid":audioid,
    "name":name,
    "title":title
  };
}

Comment: I tried fcmcrafts.insert(0, FCMContent.fromJson(_notification.data)); But although I got a notification sound, the json data didn't appear in my list.

Comment: If I print out the received _notification.data Here's what I get; {audioid: 77, name: Funny Head, title: Great Scott} So it looks like a JSON object. I just don't know how to insert it into the fcmcrafts list.